# class path for java and servlets

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

I installed Apache Tomcat for working with servlets. I set few system variables.

**CATALINA_HOME**

C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59

**CLASSPATH**

C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\lib\servlet-api.jar;

My servlets are working fine.But the problem is I couldn't load the class file using java command.If i delete the class path mentioned above i could load the class file but the servlets are not working.
What i need is a single class path that works for both of them
I also have a path in user variable

**Path**

C:\Ruby200\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin;C:\Users\Home \AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Try setting tomcat path in the PATH. I see that your tomcat is installed in C: . So in the PATH try setting C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin; and check

Comment: thanks dude!! It worked. give it as a answer so that i can accept

Comment: As suggested i have given it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting tomcat path in the PATH. I see that your tomcat is installed in C: . So in the PATH try setting C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin; and check